# MySQL trigger after update - update if columns are not null

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to update one column "status" after update record and only if four specific columns are not null. This is my trigger, but it doesn't work properly.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_thesis_rate_upade`
AFTER UPDATE ON `theses` 
FOR EACH ROW IF (new.promoterRate IS NOT NULL AND new.promoterNote IS NOT NULL AND new.reviewerNote IS NOT NULL AND new.reviewerRate IS NOT NULL) 
THEN 
UPDATE theses SET new.status="Oceniona" WHERE old.id=new.id;
 END IF;
```

When I update these columns the status column is still this same and when try change values in MySQL phpMyAdmin throw error 'cannot change because there is set trigger'. Could you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't modify the table a trigger is triggered from in the trigger; just use `SET` statements on the `NEW.fieldnames`.

```
IF some_condition THEN
  SET NEW.blah2 = 'something or other';
END IF;
```

Comment: I made this SET new.status="Oceniona"; and it throw error #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Probably should be a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger then; `AFTER` implies the data has already been written. `SET OLD.status` _might_ work in an `AFTER UPDATE` but I haven't dealt with triggers enough to be certain without trying it myself.

Comment: Ok, was just looking at trigger docs for another question and it looks like only NEW fields can be set, and only in BEFORE [INSERT|UPDATE] triggers.